# When performing Confidence Interval estimation, can I assume that the data comes from different distributions other than the normal distribution?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, statistical-significance, inference, descriptive-statistics

While studying confidence intervals, every example I have gone through assumes that the sample data comes from the normal distribution of the population. So, for the confidence interval, do I have to assume that the data comes from the normal distribution?

Comment: Confidence interval is for the mean, the mean is usually normally distributed, but not necessarily.

Comment: Do you mean that the data does not need to come from the normal distribution?

Comment: Not necessarily, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem.

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22confidence+interval%22+-normal+-gaussian+-bootstrap+score%3A2